# Nomenclature won't work

Tags: texstudio, nomenclature

I'm trying to get a nomenclature running in `LaTeX`. The problem is that the nomenclature never is printed. I got an example from [here](https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Nomenclatures):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Without printing errors this wouldn't even create a PDF.

I use Ubuntu 15.04, I have almost all texlive-packages installed, I compile using TexStudio and XeLaTex.

What must I do to get the nomenclature running?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have no typesetting text in your document!

Comment: I've deleted the `xetex` tag since this question is not related to xelatex or `xetex` at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nomencl` package needs some typeset text in the document -- otherwise it won't write the `foo.nlo` file (if the document is called foo.tex).

After the `foo.nlo` exists, it's necessary to use (in terminal or in an editor 'external utilities' command.)

```
makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o foo.nls foo.nlo
```

The `nomencl.ist` is provided by the `nomencl` package already.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

Some text

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get it running. If I copy and paste your code into `test.tex` and then compile it through TexStudio with XeLaTex, the only visible thing in the resulting `test.pdf` is "Some text". Other then that there is a `test.aux`, `test.log`, `test.nlo`, `test.ssynctex.gz`.

Comment: With `typeset` you mean "Some text", right?

Comment: @Socrates: Exactly, `Some text`, that is typesetting. Without it you have an empty document and there will be no `nomenclature`. By the way, if you use `xelatex`, what's the purpose of `\usepackage{inputenc}` then? And it works the way I wrote in my post too (even with xelatex)!

Comment: Let's assume that your main file is `foo.tex`. If you already have an `foo.nls` file, it is advisable to delete it, and run the command above `makeindex foo.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o foo.nls` with your current `foo.nlo` file. Make a copy of your nls before deleting it.

Comment: Because it took me an hour to figure this out for TeXStudio: In ``Settings --> Build``, I defined a user command ``makenomindex``, as follows: ``makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls %.nlo``, then updated the default Compiler sequence from ``txs:///pdflatex`` to ``txs:///pdflatex | txs:///makenomindex | txs:///pdflatex``. I'm not sure if that is the most robust or most elegant way of doing it, but it seems to work. I suspect that there is a better way but I've never before  modified the TeXStudio pipeline by hand, so I don't feel qualified to say.

Comment: @Zak ^^^ This was the way that worked for me, Thanks a bunch <3